# How can I make the HandleError attribute work without web.config setting (customErrors)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-5, custom-errors, handleerror

I can't get `[HandleError]` attribute in MVC 5 to work.

I have this Controller

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult WelcomePage()
    {
        throw new Exception("Oops!");
        return View();
    }
}
```

Which gives the yellow screen of death.

If I add in the web.config

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On" />
</system.web>
```

it works. But if I remove the `[HandleError]` it still works, so it's setting in the web.config has higher presedense I guess.

But should't you be able to only use the `[HandleError]` without relying on some web.config setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The HandleError filter handle exceptions only if the *customErrors* is turned on in web.config

see this link for more details:
http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/5/exception_handling_in_asp_net_mvc

Comment: So do people add the HandleError attribute or not? I mean.. I still get to the error page, without the [HandleError]. I would expect to get something extra but I might be wrong?

Comment: Oh okay I think I get it now. I have to set 'customErrors' to On, as you documented. And the reason why it works without [HandleError] is by design. But if I wanted to specify it like "[HandleError(Exception = typeof(DbException), View = "DatabaseError")]" I have to write the attribute.

Comment: HandleError filter will handle errors that occurs in the controller level. There is another way to handle controller errors other than using HandleError filter which is to override a function on the controller which is called (OnException).